# Django how to log loge page with id

Tags: django, django-views

I am new to Django and tried existing answers but did not work for me. I would appreciate your help!

I can easily get to the general page when I enter the site, but how do I go to my profile when I log in?

```
def login(request, pk=0):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        try:
            remember = request.POST['remember_me']
            if remember:
                settings.SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = False
        except:
            is_private = False
            settings.SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = True

        if user is not None:
            auth.login(request, user)
            
            return redirect('/')
        else:
            messages.info(request, 'invalid credentials')
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        return render(request, 'registration/login.html')
```

urls.py

```
 path('profile/<int:pk>/', views.profiles, name='profile'),
```

Comment: what error are you facing

Comment: i dont get error, i want just after login opended user profile page which url with <int:id>, now after log user see general page  url '/'

Comment: @MrHow, use this: `redirect('profile', pk=user.pk)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use [**redirect()**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#examples) function:

```
if user is not None:
    auth.login(request, user)
    
    return redirect('profile', pk=user.pk)
```

By passing the name of a view and optionally some positional or keyword arguments; the URL will be reverse resolved using the **[reverse()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse)** method:

Comment: unfortunately I don't understand how. User have atribute pk besides id?

Comment: yeah, see [Automatic primary key fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields)